# Is rising intonation (almost) universally associated with questions across languages, and why?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, prosody, intonation, questions

It seems that in most languages, rising intonation/prosody (towards the end of the sentence) is typically associated with questions. Thus:

1. How prevalent is this practice, and are there major counterexamples?
2. Is there any deeper explanation (e.g. psychological) why rising intonation tends to be associated with questions?

Thank you! I have been unable to find any direct references online.

Comment: Does Swahili count as a counterexample? Questions tend to be marked by a higher pitch on the _penultimate_ syllable, giving them a falling tone at the end.

Comment: @Draconis That certainly counts as a counterexample. I'm sure there are counterexamples... I'm just trying to get a sense whether the association between rising intonation and questions tends to be widespread. Further, if you have any thoughts on the second question I would appreciate that too!

Comment: English _wh_-questions also tend to have a falling tone at the end, with the higher peak coming a bit earlier; I think this is fairly common, typologically, but there’s still a rising intonation _towards_ the end, just not at the very end. In Chinese (and presumably also other tonal languages, especially if questions are lexically marked), a rising intonation is common, but no rise is also normal, the rise often signalling emphasis (e.g., “你要这个吗?” with no rise is neutral ‘do you want this one?’, with rise emphasised ‘this the one you want?’).

Comment: In Ukrainian and Russian the intonation in the general (yes/no) questions is rising at  the word the question is about, so if the question is about a word in the beginning of the sentence, the the intonation rises on this word and falls towards the end of the sentence. For example, Ukrainian: ↑Ти говориш англìйською? lit. “_You_ speak English?” meaning “Is it you who can speak English?” with intonation raising on ти “you” and falling on the last stressed sound, [i] of the last word.

Comment: From *Intonation Systems - A Survey of 20 Languages*: Bolinger
(1978b) reported that about 70% of a sample of nearly 250 languages were said
to use a rising terminal to signal questions and that the remaining 30% used a
higher overall pitch for questions than for non-questions.
In this volume a high final pitch for non-emphatic yes/no questions is said to
be a common pattern for all [20 languages surveyed] except Danish, Finnish, Hungarian, Bulgarian, Russian, Western Arabic and Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: But 'there are both questions without rises and rises without questions'.

Comment: @rchivers That surprises me – non-emphatic yes/no questions in Danish generally do have a rise at or towards the end. I would have said it was in 1978 too, but I wasn’t alive then, so I don’t speak from personal experience there.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I wouldn't know - in fairness the book does say that questions "contrast with declaratives [in Danish] by an absence of global declination". It was published in 1998 and the chapter on Danish is by Nina Grønnum.

Comment: @rchivers Well, she definitely knows what she’s talking about normally… there’s probably some aspect to her point that I’m missing.

Comment: The rising intonation finish is restricted in English syntax to yes/no questions and tags (or to embedded questions without inversion). But it's available for a surprise/suspicion take on any word or phrase one pleases, pragmatically. For instance, _President, at his age?_ But _Wh_-questions don't rise; they use full stops.

Comment: In the late '80s and early '90s very many Americans started using that rising tone to indicate the end of every declarative sentences, to the annoyance of those of us who didn't do that. They would say "Joe Biden was elected president?" and it wouldn't be a question; it would be their denial that Biden cheated. Mercifully this fad passed.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you so much. I'm wondering if the difference arises from the fact that, in some languages (e.g. Chinese), it is easy to learn that "this is a question" from the sentence alone. Therefore, the rising tone will be less needed?

Comment: @YellowSky Great point. As I think, the same is true for (some speakers) of English. A sharp rising tone is used to indicate what is being asked about. I guess I should heavily modify my question to say whether a rising tone "somewhere in the sentence" is universally used to indicate questions?

Comment: @rchivers Thanks so much for the reference. So the rising tone is indeed somewhat universal (my first question). Do you have any thoughts to the second question? My (uninformed conjecture) is this arises from the human tendency to feel that a high-pitch sentence isn't "comfortable" and thus need to "return to home pitch", just like how listeners want "closure" in tonal music. When the melody ventures to a different pitch, listeners want it to "come back to the central tone".

Comment: @jlawler Great point. I think this is related to JanusBahsJacquet's answer. I guess when the sentence is a clearly a question (e.g. Wh-questions), there is no need for a rising intonation, but otherwise, such a rising intonation is needed.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's really interesting. Is there any source (ideally video/audio) for this?

Comment: A rising intonation is definitely used in all languages I’m familiar with to indicate a question in some way, that much is true. A simple, ‘grunted’ interjection is, I think, quite close to being universally used to mean ‘what [did you say/do you mean/etc.]?’, and regardless of the exact shape of that interjection (huh, eh, hein, mm, hæ, etc.), I have never come across a language that **doesn’t** use a rising intonation for this. Conversely, affirmative grunts meaning ‘I understand/go on/yes’ usually do not have rising intonation (though some do, like ‘uh-huh’ in English).

Comment: @JLi : I haven't thought about published sources, although I think this was widely commented on in the media.

Comment: Well, I haven't read it but I see there's a 1981 paper by Cruttenden called *Falls and rises: meanings and universals* - sounds like that addresses Q2. FWIW I doubt there is a straightforward relationship. I do think that lower pitches are associated with dominance and control (bc they imply large body size) whereas higher pitches are associated with submissiveness. On a simplistic level, to assert is dominant behaviour whereas to request is submissive behaviour, so that does fit in a sense... but the reality of our interpersonal behaviour is so much more complex I'm not sure how useful it is.